# Cookiejar use in an opener

Tags: python, urllib2, cookiejar, cookielib

I have the following code at the moment:

```
tw_jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
tw_jar.set_cookie(c1)
tw_jar.set_cookie(c2)

o = urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(tw_jar) )
urllib2.install_opener( o )
```

Now I later in my code I don't want to use any of the cookies (Also new cookies created meanwhile).

Can I do a simple `tw_jar.clear()` or do I need to build and install the opener again to get rid of all cookies used in the requests?

Comment: Do you need to clear old cookies, but still continue processing new ones or don't use any cookie at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how `HTTPCookieProcessor` is defined in my Python installation:

```
class HTTPCookieProcessor(BaseHandler):
  def __init__(self, cookiejar=None):
    import cookielib
    if cookiejar is None:
        cookiejar = cookielib.CookieJar()
    self.cookiejar = cookiejar

  def http_request(self, request):
    self.cookiejar.add_cookie_header(request)
    return request

  def http_response(self, request, response):
    self.cookiejar.extract_cookies(response, request)
    return response

  https_request = http_request
  https_response = http_response
```

As only a reference is saved, you can just manipulate the original `tw_jar` instance and it will affect all future requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any cookies, I'd recommend to create a new opener. However, if for some reason you want to keep the old one, removing the cookie processor from the list of handlers should work:

```
o.handlers = [h for h in o.handlers
              if not isinstance(h, urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor)]
```